# Dependent choice and Zorn's Lemma

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

How much of Zorn's lemma can be saved if we assume only ZF+DC without full choice?
More precisely: assume we have a partially ordered (inductive) set which is of size continuum. Then can we apply Zorn's lemma in this case assuming only dependent choice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a theorem of Wolk [1] that for every infinite $\kappa$ the axiom $\sf DC_\kappa$ is equivalent to the following statement:

> If $(P,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set in which every well-ordered chain has order type $<\kappa$ and has an upper-bound, then $P$ contains a maximal element.

In the case of $\kappa=\omega$ this means that every partial order in which every well-ordered chain is finite and bounded has a maximal element.

Note that there is no limitation on the cardinality of $P$. Only on its well-ordered chains.

---

**Bibliography:**

1. Elliot S. Wolk, **[On the principle of dependent choices and some forms of Zorn’s lemma](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CMB-1983-062-5)**, *Canad. Math. Bull.* **26** (1983), no. 3, 365–367.

Comment: What can we save ($DC_{\omega}$ or $DC_{\aleph_1}$) in Solovay's model?

Comment: Solovay's model **satisfies** $\sf DC_\omega$. When we say "save" we mean that we *can* construct a model in such way that $\sf DC_\omega$ (or otherwise) is retained. It cannot satisfy $\sf DC_{\aleph_1}$ as that implies there is a non-measurable set.